# Sorting , lazing loading considerations

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am creating a grid that provides sorting functionality. It uses D3 js . Currently the data set is around 2000 records but in the future this could be a large number i.e in 10,000 to 1 million.

Should client js scripts be used for sorting or should it done on server assuming we have a large recordset.
Also I would at what point should I be considering lazy loading of data for the table.

Thanks

Comment: Is the data being pulled from a database? If so, you should certainly sort the data set and return a limited amount of rows server-side.

Comment: Yes data is pulled from server. The columns are almost around 20 for now , but it can grow in number. Plus we do want a way for the user to sort the data on columns presented in the table.

Comment: Add pagenation at the client. Send sort order, page size and current page index to server. Filter data at data base and get only specific data using MS SQL functions like skip and fetch.

Comment: Yes, what Bhasyakurulu said, for MySQL this would be "SORT BY [column name]" and "LIMIT [start row], [end row]"

Comment: What's the use case? Are the users expected do do a large amount of manipulation of the data? In some cases it may make sense to pull down all the data and manipulate it client-side; however, this will not be efficient for large numbers of rows (and may time-out or hang your server).